# How to create groups based on dct.keys in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function, dictionary

I want to create groups based on dictionary keys. If key is in more than one dictionary I want to create group that I can use later. I almost succeded but I can't get desired output. As you can see below there are two possible groups. That is dct1 and dct3 (same key 18) and dct 2 and dct 4 (same key 8). Below is what I've created so far.

```
dct1 = {20: [(87, 6), (87, 7)],
        21: [(68, 8)],
        18: [(30, 7)],
        11: [(27, 7), (28, 7)]}

dct2 = {8: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        14: [(4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7)],
        16: [(58, 7), (56, 7), (57, 7)]}

dct3 = {4: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        15: [(77, 7), (78, 7)],
        18: [(29, 9), (29, 8)],
        3: [(27, 7), (28, 7)]}

dct4 = {8: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        30: [(6, 9), (5, 7), (7, 9)],
        35: [(58, 7), (56, 7), (57, 7)]}

rwawl = [dct1, dct2, dct3, dct4]


def group_rooms(rectangles_with_adjacent_walls_list):
    groups = []
    for rectangle in rectangles_with_adjacent_walls_list:
        adjacent_wall_list = rectangle.keys()
        if not groups:
            groups.append([adjacent_wall_list])
        print adjacent_wall_list
        new_group_threshold = len(adjacent_wall_list)
        new_group = 0

        for adjacent_wall in adjacent_wall_list:
            for added_room in groups:
                if adjacent_wall in added_room:
                    added_room.append(adjacent_wall_list)
                    break
                else:
                    new_group += 1

            if new_group == new_group_threshold:
                groups.append([adjacent_wall_list])

    print groups
    return groups


created_groups = group_rooms(rwawl)

# MY OUTPUT:
# [[[18, 11, 20, 21]], [[18, 11, 20, 21]], [[18, 3, 4, 15]], [[8, 35, 30]]]

# DESIRED OUTPUT:
# [[[18, 11, 20, 21], [18, 3, 4, 15]], [[8, 16, 14], [8, 35, 30]]]
```

Comment: If there is a key say 10 in all the dicts. What would your desired output look like?

Comment: Checked it for you. It creates one list inside list and then in one more list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces your desired output, at least for the example you gave. This will create a group for **every** key that occurs in multiple dicts:

```
def group_rooms(dicts):
    key_sets = [set(d.keys()) for d in dicts]
    # union of all keys
    total_keys = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, key_sets, set())
    key_groups = [map(list, filter(lambda s: k in s,  key_sets)) for k in total_keys]
    # return groups with removed singletons
    return filter(lambda s: len(s) > 1, key_groups)
```

Comment: lists_with_key.values is not defined. Also is it possible to say what is going in this code I can just copy paste it by don't understand much of what happens in here.

Comment: please have a look at my answer. similar inspiration to this post and perhaps a bit more readable.

Comment: Oh lists_with_key.values should be replaced with key_groups. There remains one problem. Code doesn't create group if there is one key in dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I had changed the dict to a list after the fact :)

Comment: It seems like code doesn't create group for keys that don't have pair. Example: dct5 = {99: [(40, 2)]}

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [dct1, dct2, dct3, dct4]
b = [i.keys() for i in a]
print [[i,j] for i,j in combinations(b,2) if set(i) & set(j) ]
```

output:

```
[[[18, 11, 20, 21], [18, 3, 4, 15]], [[8, 16, 14], [8, 35, 30]]]
```

Comment: What if a key occurs in 3 dicts? You will create three groups of two.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

dct1 = {20: [(87, 6), (87, 7)],
        21: [(68, 8)],
        18: [(30, 7)],
        11: [(27, 7), (28, 7)]}

dct2 = {8: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        14: [(4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7)],
        16: [(58, 7), (56, 7), (57, 7)]}

dct3 = {4: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        15: [(77, 7), (78, 7)],
        18: [(29, 9), (29, 8)],
        20: [(27, 7), (28, 7)]}

dct4 = {8: [(41, 5), (41, 6), (41, 4)],
        30: [(6, 9), (5, 7), (7, 9)],
        35: [(58, 7), (56, 7), (57, 7)]}

dct5 = {99: [(1, 1)]}

l = [dct1, dct2, dct3, dct4, dct5]

key_map = defaultdict(list)
all_keys = set()
for d in l:
    all_keys.add(tuple(d.keys()))
    for k in d.keys():
        key_map[k].append(tuple(d.keys()))
dup_keys = [tuple(v) for k, v in key_map.items() if len(v) > 1]
unique_dup_keys = set(itertools.chain(*dup_keys))
diff = all_keys - unique_dup_keys

dup_keys = set(dup_keys)

key_groups = list((dup_keys | diff))
print(key_groups)

# [((8, 16, 14), (8, 35, 30)), (99,), ((18, 11, 20, 21), (20, 18, 4, 15))]
```

Comment: seems like code doesn't create group for keys that don't have pair ( example dct5 = {99: [(40, 2)]} )

Comment: I modified the code to include unpaired dictionaries.